# Karnaugh maps how i put them exactly

Tags: karnaugh-map

Hello i have issue how i locate the variables on karnaugh maps.I know what to do but i have the problem how i locate it.What i mean by that as you can see i have this:

> F=A'B'C'+B'CD'+A'BCD'+AB'C' this 
>   is
>    F=B'D'B'C'+A'CD'

what i want to understand because i can't and why happens this is.
I know how work the Karnaugh but i cant have the ABC in first line?or A'B'C' or B'CD what i wrote..And how much lines for this specific exercise?I have 4 so i think i will do 4.What i think is ABC',AB'C',A'BCD',thats how the lines will be my thought

Comment: Why do you have B' written twice i.e. F=B'D'B'C' etc..

Comment: You have both a space and enter key on your keyboard. Use them.

Answer (score 1):

F is in SOP form in terms of 4 variables A,B,C,D. Various Elements in the SOP expression for F are called Minterms.

1)  4 variables, means K-map can be drawn as 4x4.

2) Total 16 cells would be there. Each cell in K-map corresponds to a minterm.

For eg. first cell --> 0000 --> A'B'C'D'

3) Look at all the minterms present in the SOP expression for F, and put '1' in the corresponding cell of the K-map.

4) Fill the rest of the cells with 0.

Comment: 4 variable: A, B, C D.

Comment: Oh yes....correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

[image]

The red 1's come from A'B'C', the blue from B'CD', the green from A'BCD', and the purple form AB'C'

From this I simply by combining the middle four 1s to get B'D', the bottom row purple and red to get B'C'D', and the loan green remains A'BCD'

F = B'D'+B'C'D'+A'BCD'